# Open window maximised on X startup

Tags: xorg, window-manager, cinnamon, window-management

I have a .xsession script. I am opening a gnome-terminal in background. I would like to open it maximised. I use Cinnamon as window manager. I do understand usually window manager is responsible for resizing client X applications when maximise button is clicked.

I want to know whether there is any  way to achieve this.

```
~$ cat .xsession
google-chrome > /dev/null 2>&1 &
gnome-terminal &
gnome-session --session cinnamon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to do

```
gnome-terminal --maximize
```

For some more powerful options, try [DevilsPie](https://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie).

Comment: `--maximize` was not documented in `man` pages of `gnome-terminal`. can you explain how this is option processed? Is it based on some screen information from X server?

Comment: It's listed under `gnome-terminal --help-all`.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, if there is such an option, obviously, use it.

For other cases, I have found that the below code works.

The loop is there because if it weren't, the fullscreen command would fire off to soon, **before** there were such a window to put in fullscreen!

`wmctrl -l` is to list windows; `wc -l` is to count lines; `wmctrl -r` is to specify what window to operate on, and, with `-b`, you tell what to actually do to that window.

```
my-application &
while (( ! `wmctrl -l | my-application | wc -l` )) {}
wmctrl -r my-application -b toggle,fullscreen
```

Comment: this requires `wmctrl -r Terminal -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz`. fullscreen causes to lose the title bar of the window.

Comment: @rag: Right, fullscreen is fullscreen.