# Gnome 3: open and resize application at startup

Tags: xorg, gnome3, startup

I need to open a couple of terminal windows and watch the output of a couple of programs.

Currently I open them in `~/.profile`, then once in Gnome I click them to bring them to the front, then resize them, then select "Always on top", then move them to a specific spot on my screen.

Can this all be done automatically? [Similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66979/open-window-maximised-on-x-startup), but I am not very familiar with X, and maybe Gnome offers an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome is a EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager. You should use [`wmctrl`](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) to interact with the windows that works very well.

```
wmctrl -r part-of-title-string -e 0,100,200,300,400
```

sets a window with "part-of-title-string" in the title to width 300, height 400
at position 100,200 (the 0 is for default gravity).

```
wmctrl -r part-of-title-string -b add,above
```

makes sure that window is always on top.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anything about the "Always on top" property?

Comment: @Vorac added that to the answer

Comment: I just discovered that `gnome-terminal` supports `--geometry=WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF`, that is, an X call to set geometry.